# Wkhtmltopdf used in laravel 8 not displaying images and charts

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, laravel-8, laravel-snappy

I'm having issues with wkhtmltopdf. Images are not showing and also javascript charts (google charts/highcharts) arent displaying on my PDF.
Using laravel 8, windows 10, XAMPP, Apache

*I tried the wrapper of mikehaertl -> plain html is displayed on PDF, but only without charts and images
Direct outside pages are displayed with images (like http://www.google.com), but not with charts.

*snappy barryvdh -> only working when I use below binary in config/snappy.php.
'binary' => base_path('vendor/wemersonjanuario/wkhtmltopdf-windows/bin/32bit/wkhtmltopdf'),
But also no charts and images displaying. Direct outside pages gives error HOSTNOTFOUNDERROR

*I tried several tutorials.
Tried url/base_path/asset to show the images.
Wkhtmltopdf is working properly when used on the command line.
Tried different javascript-delay's, no-stop-slow-scripts

What else is there to try? Thanks in advance!